# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to customize WL.BusyIndicator's height and width?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am using busyindicator in worklight 6.1 version for `ios` environment and want to know how to increase height and width for indicator. Code for showing busy indicator which i am using

```
busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator('content', {text : 'Loading Data Please Wait....'});
busyInd.show()  //for showing indicator 
busyInd.hide()  // for Hiding indicator
```

It is showing me busyIndicator but it is very small and text is too long which is not showing properly. I want to customize the height and width. Can i do that or is there any way to do that or it it there can you provide me syntax for that.

Comment: Vishal, when you are asking a question you need to also mention the Worklight environment(s) you are building your application for. We cannot help you otherwise. Please always provide FULL details.

Comment: K, I updated my question.Please check this is for `ios` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `boxLength` property, [as mentioned in the documentation for WL.BusyIndicator](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.BusyIndicator.html).

For example, in `common\main.js`:

```
var busy;

function wlCommonInit(){
    busy = new WL.BusyIndicator ("content", {text : 'Loading Data Please Wait....', boxLength: 255.5});
    busy.show();
}
```

P.S.,
There is a slight documentation issue here; I've opened a defect to correct it.

Comment: Thanks it works for me but please let me know me in 'boxLength: 255.5'  what is the height and width. Because i am not able to differentiate. It's showing me square box always or it is the behaviour of Indicator.

Comment: 255.5 is the width, the height is automatically calculated based on this value.