# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Does WL.BusyIndicator support text wrapping for iOS?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

Attached is the code for we have implemented for the busy indicator on iOS. But this does not wrap the busyText on iOS.

```
$.r.setBusyIndicator(new WL.BusyIndicator('content', {
    opacity : 0.65,
    fullScreen : false,
    text : busyText
}));
```

Comment: Provide the text you are using for the busy indicator, which you say does not wrap.

Comment: "Ouverture de session" is the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping is not available.

You can use a different busy indicator altogether: a native busy implementation by you, or an indicator provided by a 3rd party library (jQuery Mobile, ...), etc.

Otherwise, you need to use the `boxLength` property which controls the height and width of the busy square holding the text, like this:

```
var busy = new WL.BusyIndicator(null, {
    text: "Ouverture de session",
    boxLength: 170 // Play with this value.
});
busy.show();
```

Related question: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to customize WL.BusyIndicator's height and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784146/ibm-worklight-6-1-how-to-customize-wl-busyindicators-height-and-width)

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Will try and update if it fixes the issue. So we can increase the box size but we cannot wrap the text inside ?

Comment: @user3412030, if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.