# Worklight busy indicator resize

Tags: css, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

The busy indicator getting resized on orientation change in IOS. Is there a way, we can give fixed height and width for the busy indicator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the following question: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Does WL.BusyIndicator support text wrapping for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712677/ibm-worklight-6-0-does-wl-busyindicator-support-text-wrapping-for-ios/23712836#23712836)

For example:

```
var busy = new WL.BusyIndicator(null, {
    text: "Ouverture de session",
    boxLength: 170 // Play with this value to change the size of the indicator 'box'.
});
busy.show();
```

However, this unfortunately does not "translate" well when changing to landscape mode...

What you could do is:

- Look at other indicator solutions, provided for example by jQuery Mobile or jQuery plug-ins
- Detect orientation change in native code and then hide the busy and re-show it based on a recalculations..

You should probably go with the first option...
Note though this this means you cannot use `WL.BusyIndicator.show/hide`; you'll need to use the API provided by the plug-in.